# Lock screen with multi-factor authentication (biometric and pattern)

Tags: security, lock-screens

Is there a way to require two forms of authentication to unlock your device? My preference would be to use my fingerprint sensor *in addition to* an unlock pattern.

I'm using a Nexus 6p with Android 7.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda know what u mean but if your fingerprint does not recognize on your phone, they will prompt you with the backup PIN.

Edit : There is no way of doing that as far as i know